# Add a column of lists to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe that contains lists. Simple example:

```
x <- data.frame(x=c(1:5))
x$y <- rep(list(item = "a"), 5)

x
```

This prints:

```
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 3 a
4 4 a
5 5 a
```

What I am looking for is instead:

```
  x y
1 1 list(item = "a")
2 2 list(item = "a")
3 3 list(item = "a")
4 4 list(item = "a")
5 5 list(item = "a")
```

Comment: Is your question about the print method? Check `str(x)` to see `y` contains the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use *tidyverse* functions, you can use the *tibble* (which is a slightly extended version of the data.frame) which allows for **list columns**.

Normally, columns of data.frames or tibbles are *vectors*, but as dataframes are lists themselves why not extend this idea. And that's what tibbles do.

Here are some examples:

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- tibble(x = c(1:5))

# add a vector column to demonstrate how "scalars" get repeated automatically
x %>% 
  mutate(z = 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       x     z
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5
#> 2     2     5
#> 3     3     5
#> 4     4     5
#> 5     5     5

# Add a list column consisting of a char vector of length one per table cell
x %>% 
  # gets repeated 5 times
  mutate(y = list("a"))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       x y        
#>   <int> <list>   
#> 1     1 <chr [1]>
#> 2     2 <chr [1]>
#> 3     3 <chr [1]>
#> 4     4 <chr [1]>
#> 5     5 <chr [1]>

# Add a list column consisting of a list with "a" 
x %>% 
  # gets repeated 5 times
  mutate(y = list(list("a")))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       x y         
#>   <int> <list>    
#> 1     1 <list [1]>
#> 2     2 <list [1]>
#> 3     3 <list [1]>
#> 4     4 <list [1]>
#> 5     5 <list [1]>


# add an "irregular" list column
x %>% 
  mutate(y = list("a", "a", list("a", "b"), "c", "d"))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       x y         
#>   <int> <list>    
#> 1     1 <chr [1]> 
#> 2     2 <chr [1]> 
#> 3     3 <list [2]>
#> 4     4 <chr [1]> 
#> 5     5 <chr [1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach works fine as far as I understand. The column `y` looks like a normal column but it holds the lists. Try `str` to see.

```
str(x)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ y:List of 5
  ..$ item: chr "a"
  ..$ item: chr "a"
  ..$ item: chr "a"
  ..$ item: chr "a"
  ..$ item: chr "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
x <- data.frame(x=c(1:5))
x$y <- rep('list(item = "a")', 5)

x
```